# jquery image tooltip

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve here is an image tooltip. When I hover over a link, the corresponding image will show up.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
.tooltipcontent{
position:absolute;
display:none;
opacity:0.0;

}

</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jq.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){

$('a').hover(

    function(){
         var currentimg= $(this).html();
         var offset =$('#link1').offset();
         $("div img[src='" + currentimg +".jpg']").css('top', offset.top).css('left', offset.left).css('display','block');
         $("div img[src='" + currentimg +".jpg']").animate({opacity: 1.0}, 300);


    },
    function(){}


);
});



</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class='tooltipcontent' id='tooltip1'>
<img src='numone.jpg'></img>
<img src='numtwo.jpg'></img>
</div>

<div id='link1'><a href='numone' target='_blank' id='viewlarger'>numone</a></div>
<div id='link2'><a href='numtwo' target='_blank' id='viewlarger'>numtwo</a></div>

 <input type='text' value='a'></input>
<div id='forimage'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that even though you're showing the `<img>`, from your styling the *parent* is still hidden:

```
.tooltipcontent {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  opacity:0.0;
}
```

I *think* you want this here:

```
.tooltipcontent img {
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  opacity:0.0;
}
```

There are some other issues to address, for example `<img>` and `<input>` tags are self-closing, and your `mouseleave` handler (the second function for [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)) needs some additions.  Something like this is more what you're probably after:

```
$(function(){
  $('a').hover(function(){
     var currentimg= $(this).html();
     $("div img[src='" + currentimg +".jpg']").css($(this).offset()).fadeIn(300);
  }, function(){        
     var currentimg= $(this).html();
     $("div img[src='" + currentimg +".jpg']").css($(this).offset()).fadeOut(300);
  });
});
```

...and remove the `opacity: 0.0;` from the CSS.  [You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/AxQw6/).